# EWS Managed API Getting Error "DTD dtd is prohibited in this xml document"

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

While searching for allitems folder I am getting "dtd is prohibited in this xml document" error. Below is the sample code that I am executing

```
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);

        string exchangeURL = "ExchangeURL";

        Uri myUri = new Uri(exchangeURL);
        service.TraceEnabled = true;
        service.Url = myUri;
        service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("email", "password");
        //service.AutodiscoverUrl(empMail.PrimaryEmail);
        service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, empMail.EmployeeEmail);

        //Certificate validation handling
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (se, cert, chain, sslerror) =>
        {
            return true;
        };


                EmailMessage message;
                PropertySet propertySet;

                Mailbox mailBox = new Mailbox("Email");
                ItemView itemView = new ItemView(1);
                itemView.Traversal = ItemTraversal.Shallow;

                //Try to get 'Allitems' folder so that we could search items in all folders
                FolderId fid = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root);
                FolderView fv = new FolderView(1);
                fv.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Shallow;

                ExtendedPropertyDefinition epd = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(13825, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
                SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(epd, "2");
                SearchFilter sf2 = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "allitems");
                SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection sfc = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And);
                sfc.Add(sf);
                sfc.Add(sf2);
                FindFoldersResults findAllItemsFolderresult = service.FindFolders(fid, sfc, fv);
```

This was working for years and when we changed the server this worked for few months then started giving this error. Please let me know the reason for this error and its solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you enable tracing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-trace-requests-responses-to-troubleshoot-ews-managed-api-applications and look at the response that is causing the issue. It maybe your getting a non EWS reply eg from a proxy or firewall etc

Comment: Thanks Glen, the above helped in getting the actual error
<!DOCTYPEHTMLPUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at
 [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
</body></html>

Comment: Looking further into the error

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's due to firewall settings.
My Exchange URL was "`https://mail.{websitedomainname}.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx`" and I received the message "*DTD is prohibited in this xml document*".

Changing the URL to "`https://xx.xx.x.xx/EWS/Exchange.asmx`" i.e. using public IP, resolved the issue.